# convert for loop to Timer Schedule

Tags: java, android, for-loop, timer, timertask

I have this `for loop`:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= right_num ; i++ ){
    for(int u = 1 ; u <= left_num ; u++ ){
        int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("c"+u+"_r"+i, "id", this.getPackageName());
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_circle);
    }
}
```

and i want to convert it to a `Timer Schedule` , and set the time between changes `250 ms`.

how to do this ?

Comment: so you want to display something like Animation? if yes, you can use AnimationDrawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: great , please answer for give you the accepted answer.

Comment: glad to help you... and let the comment to be a comment. thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i=0;
int total_time=250*left_num*right_num;
private CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(total_time, 250) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int u=i%left_num+1,v=i/left_num+1;
            int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("c"+u+"_r"+v, "id", this.getPackageName());
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_circle);
            i++;
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
```

Let me know if it helps